# Sort a Grid when after loading all data in the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid with 4 columns 'Id' 'Name' ' Address' 'Age'
I getting all the Id's in the list and binding to the grid. Now in Grid_itemDataBound event depending upon the Id I am getting the Name, Address Age for that particular row.
now I want to sort the grid depending on the Name.
How I can Sort depending on the Name which was binded to grid in Item databound
Please do Needful

my Code

```
grdEmployee.DataSource = lstEmployee.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();

protected void grdEmployee_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lblname = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblName");
    Label lblAge = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblAge");
    Label lblId = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblId");

    lblName.Text = GetName(lblId.Text);
    lblAge.Text = GetAge(lblId.Text);   
}
```

Note: this is sample code I have manually written in this editor. please Ignore faults in the code and please understand my scenario.

Comment: Is there some special reason for getting data in parts - first ID, then Name, Age and Address?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it would be better if you get all the data at once, then doing it in parts in each call to ItemDataBound. This way instead of just a list of ID you will have a DataTable or a List of Employees. And then you can sort this DataTable or List the way you like - using DefaultView.Sort (for DataTable) or LINQ OrderBy.